# 5.5.1 Authentication Required: Error trying to send a mail with .NET c# or vb

Tags: c#, email, authentication, required

New secure setting on GOOGLE WORLD avoid using test code using your custom Gmail accounts.

The full Error is: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Enter to this site when logged on your gmail account and enabled "Access Less Secure Apps"

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

that all!